# Search / Export MS Access Schema and Forms

Tags: microsoft-access

I am adding features to a complex Access database with many forms, tables, and queries.  It is often quite challenging to locate the source of some behavior.

*Is it VBA code? Is it a form property? Which forms reference a specific table? What restricts this dropdown to only these specific items? etc*

**Question:**

How can I search for some specific text across the entire structure of an Access database: table properties, column properties, VBA code, form object properties, etc?

*Possible approach:* Export entire structure to XML (how?) then search with text editor.